# Not able to open pgAdmin 4 "Loading pgAdmin 4 v7.4..."

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to open pgAdmin 4 in postgreSQL but its loading constantly....

What should  i do , I think its version issue or something else

I also try in another laptop but showing same issue and

during the installation i change nothing on it and click next-next only

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem follow the following steps:

1. Open registry editor. (search for Run then type `regedit` then press enter).
2. Search for `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js` and change the `Content Type` from `text/plain` to `text/javascript`.
3. Restart pgAdmin and then it should work.

If you are still facing the same problem you can downgrade to V7.3.

You can download it from this link: [PgAdmin Download link](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-windows/)

Answer (score 1):

First, while installing PostgreSQL from the website (https://www.postgresql.org/download/) based on your platform, before the installation process it prompts you to select the components you wish to install. Only select "PostgreSQL Server" and "Command Line Tools" out of the four options provided, and proceed.

Then, navigate to the website to download PgAdmin (https://www.pgadmin.org/download/). Launch the installer and complete the installation process.

Now, the issue of PgAdmin loading eternally would be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Click [issue from Github pgAdmin](https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues/6580)!
You have to uninstall with EDB installer, and reinstall with this link to download the 7.5 version. https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-windows/